# Bootstrap: navbar row with display:table not working with width:100% & vertical-align:middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5aw2w9w6/

The code is like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color:#FF0000">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="width:100%;display:table; table-layout:fixed; vertical-align:middle">
       <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2"style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
          <!-- content -->
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-8" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
          <!-- content -->
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2"style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;text-align:right">
          <!-- content -->
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

2 things are broken:

1) The `width:100%` on the row is not working. If you do an inspect element in the fiddle, you'll see that the `navbar` and `container` stretch the full width of the screen, but the `row` does not. This is also made evident in that the last `col-xs-*` has a `text-align:right`. As you can see in the fiddle, there's still a gap between the cart button and the right edge of the screen

2) The `vertical-align:middle` is not working. If it were, I'd expect the cart button to not touch the top edge of the screen, and instead be aligned middle (vertically) relative to the logo image (white, it's the content in the first section)

Answer (score 0):

1. The check your container it has a max-width of `width: 750px;` that's why it doesn't touch the edges of the screen
2. For the vertical align middle please set height to your table row and the other reason why ain't work is because the
   `float:left` of every column try to remove it and see it will work fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/nzjqua4s/1/

Comment: #2 was super helpful! #1 I don't see what you're saying, when I do an inspect element, I don't see max-width anywhere, not on the `container` element, can you take a screenshot of your inspect element?

Comment: In your fiddle I still see that the row is not 100% of the container, and that the button is not touching the right edge of the screen, so I'm a bit confused still...

Comment: yes, you can see this code in my fiddle <div class="container" style="width:100%"> it overwrite the max-width:750px of container and for the "cart" or column that is not touching the edges of the screen check the padding of the column and the container and remove also the width:100% of the table

Comment: Ah OK, so then the correct answer is to ADD width:100% to the container but REMOVE it from the row, can you change the fiddle for anyone else who might be interested? Thanks!

Comment: follow up question. On the image there is also a width:100%. If you remove that, then problem #2 happens again, any idea why?